# How to disable direct URL access in a Spring Boot Application?

Tags: spring-boot, embedded-tomcat-8

We have a Spring Boot application with Embedded Tomcat configured using a YAML file. Client side scripting is in AngularJS.

The problem is that a user can see the HTML contents of a page when using the direct URL.

For example, our primary login page opens when **https://localhost:7001/** is requested, but static HTML content can be seen when somebody who knows the page location on the server directly requests **https://localhost:7001/views/dashboard.html**.

This is a security flaw and I want such requests to be blocked or re-directed to the login page.  Is there any configuration for Embedded Tomcat to block direct access?